# $4\int_{-4}^{0} \sqrt{-y} \,dy$

Tags: calculus, integration

Isn't $$4\int_{-4}^{0} \sqrt{-y} \,dy = 4(0-16/3)=-64/3 ?$$

How come the answer I see is $64/3$, without the negative sign?

Comment: The positive sign is correct.  If you show your working (edit it into your question) someone can probably tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: The integral represents the area under the curve, and $\sqrt {-y}$ is above the x-axis for $x<0$, so the integral gives a positive value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a substitution:

$$u=-y\implies du=-dy\implies$$

$$4\int\limits_{-4}^0\sqrt{-y}\;dy=4\int\limits_4^0\sqrt u\;(-du)=4\int\limits_0^4\sqrt u\;du=$$

$$\left.4\cdot\frac23 u^{3/2}\right|_0^4=\frac{8}3(4^{3/2}-0)=\frac{64}3$$

Not minus, not what you wrote...unless I made a mistake, of course.

Comment: I suppose that $24$ is $8$ which then leads to $\frac{64}3$ !!

Comment: I fixed the fraction to avoid confusion.

Comment: Than you, @anorton. +1